# Expectation of (non-linear) transformed random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, square-numbers

If I have a two correlated normal distributed random variables, i.e. $A \sim N(m_a,\sigma_a^2)$ and $B \sim N(0,1)$, with correlation coefficient $ Corr(A,B) =\rho$, then I want to define a random variable $ R = e^{\frac{1}{2}A}B$.

I found out that $ E[R] = \frac{1}{2} \rho \sigma_a^2 e^{\frac{1}{2}m_a + \frac{1}{8}\sigma_a^2}$

My question: What ist $E[R^2]$ ?

Comment: How did you find $E[R]$? To me $E[R^2]$ looks the same in the sense that we have $E[f(A,B)] = \int ... \phi(a,b) da db$ where $\phi$ is the joint pdf of $(A,B)$

Comment: I used the tower property (conditional on $A$) and later on Stein's Lemma. But this doesn't work anymore, since I need to know the covariance of $A$ and $B^2$.